# Strange behaviour on iptable with nat AND port forwarding

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, port-forwarding, dnat

I have several dedicated servers hosted in several datacenters, and I want to migrate mail (**pop3**, **imap**, **smtp** and their TLS/SSL variants) services from one server to another.

For that purpose, I intend to temporarily install a *NAT* routing on the new server to the old one for handling the time of DNS propagation.

So I defined the following **IPTABLES** rules :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25  -j DNAT --to-destination <my_remote_ip>:8025
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j DNAT --to-destination <my_remote_ip>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DNAT --to-destination <my_remote_ip>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DNAT --to-destination <my_remote_ip>:8465
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination <my_remote_ip>:8587
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DNAT --to-destination <my_remote_ip>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j DNAT --to-destination <my_remote_ip>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110  -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143  -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993  -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995  -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8025 -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>:25
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8465 -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>:465
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8587 -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>:587

iptables -A FORWARD -d <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8025 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8587 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 143  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 993  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 995  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8025 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8465 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s <my_remote_ip> -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8587 -j ACCEPT
```

(actually simplified, in fact this is duplicated for IPv4 and IPV6, and on some servers the interface may be different than eth0 … and of course I mangled the actual IP addresses)

You may note that mail services are only NAT'ed, but that SMTP related services have also a **port translation**, associated with either the reverse translation or the specific listening of these ports on the destination server.

There is a compelling reason for that: my hosting provider uses to monitor outgoing SMTP connections in order to detect and block spam hosted on all servers hosted by them. But if I forward incoming connections to SMTP port to another of my servers, **incoming spam** becomes **outgoing spam** *(from the point of view of the datacenter)* before it has any chances to be filtered *(on the destination server)*, and the result is that my hosting provider immediately blocks the NAT'ting server.

So I have to translate also the port number in order to forward these connections.

Incoming packets and outgoing (NAT'ed) packets use the same interface *(because these servers have only one network interface)*.

Actually this works more or less, except that the port forwarded connections (**and only these ones**, no problem on ports 110, 143, etc) have a strange behaviour: they work the first time I use them, but if I disconnect and reconnect immediately, the forwarding no longer works and I have to wait about 1 to 3 minutes before being able to connect again.

This seems to be related to the IP address, not to the port number: Even if the previous connection was on port 110 (pop3, not port forwarded), I have to wait the same delay before being able to connect to port 25.

I have verified that on several servers, all of them being **Linux Debian Wheezy**, **Jessie** or **Stretch**, and on both **IPv4** and **IPv6** *(except on Wheezy which cannot NAT IPv6)*. ……… Yes, I know that Wheezy is now old, this is why I am migrating.

All IP addresses are fully static.

And yes, I have set **/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward** (and it's IPv6 equivalent) to **1**.

I use **telnet** for testing the connections, and I check the forwarding with **tcpdump**. With the latter I can check that the forwarding is really not done, and that it is *not* the destination server which blocks the incoming connections.

Please could someone help me to find the reason of this 1-3 minutes blocking delay and how I could fix it?

Gingko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue relates to especialities of the linux connection tracker.

The quick answer: you cannot avoid this delay in your configuration. Only way is avoid this issue is usage the `-j SNAT` without a port number specification in the `--to-source` option.

There is also a little trick, that can little help you - use in the `j SNAT` the range of ports instead single port number. It'll able you establish multiple connections. Number of the simultanious connections is number of ports in the range. The rule will seem like:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d <my_remote_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8025 -j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>:10025-10125`

If you want the bloody details, I can extend the answer.

#### Update

To understand the details, you should have some background. Read `"Linux kernel networking: implementation and theory"` by Rami Rosen. Mainly you need the "Chapter 9. Netfilter. Connection tracker" from this book.

When the packets go through your linux host, the linux connection tracker (`conntrack`) analyze them and store the information about packet flows into the table (`conntrack table`). Every packet flow is presented as the conntrack entry. The conntrack uses tuples to identified packet flows. Tuples consist of **L3** (ip addresses of both ends and number of L4 protocol) and **L4** (for TCP this is port numbers information of both ends) information of flows.

The conntrack has some modules for every L4 protocols to trace the transport protocol specific states of connections. The TCP conntrack part implements the TCP finite state machine.

In the lab (kernel 4.14) there is a strange behavious of this TCP conntrack part. Let's I demonstrate this on the simple environment.

Client (`192.0.2.2`) connects to the linux host (`192.0.2.1:22`), that forwards this connection to other host (`192.0.2.6:22`). The linux host also uses SNAT rule like in your setup.

The tcpdump output:

```
14:47:32.036809 IP 192.0.2.2.40079 > 192.0.2.1.22: Flags [S], seq 2159011818, win 29200, length 0
14:47:32.037346 IP 192.0.2.1.22 > 192.0.2.2.40079: Flags [S.], seq 960236935, ack 2159011819, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1415987649 ecr 3003498128,nop,wscale 5], length 0
14:47:32.037683 IP 192.0.2.2.40079 > 192.0.2.1.22: Flags [.], ack 1, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 3003498129 ecr 1415987649], length 0
14:47:32.041407 IP 192.0.2.1.22 > 192.0.2.2.40079: Flags [P.], seq 1:22, ack 1, win 905, options [nop,nop,TS val 1415987653 ecr 3003498129], length 21
14:47:32.041806 IP 192.0.2.2.40079 > 192.0.2.1.22: Flags [.], ack 22, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 3003498133 ecr 1415987653], length 0
14:47:35.826919 IP 192.0.2.2.40079 > 192.0.2.1.22: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 22, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 3003501918 ecr 1415987653], length 0
14:47:35.827996 IP 192.0.2.1.22 > 192.0.2.2.40079: Flags [F.], seq 22, ack 2, win 905, options [nop,nop,TS val 1415991440 ecr 3003501918], length 0
14:47:35.828386 IP 192.0.2.2.40079 > 192.0.2.1.22: Flags [.], ack 23, win 913, options [nop,nop,TS val 3003501919 ecr 1415991440], length 0
```

In the conntrack on the linux host I see this:

```
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431999 ESTABLISHED src=192.0.2.2 dst=192.0.2.1 sport=40079 dport=22 src=192.0.2.6 dst=192.0.2.5 sport=22 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431998 ESTABLISHED src=192.0.2.2 dst=192.0.2.1 sport=40079 dport=22 src=192.0.2.6 dst=192.0.2.5 sport=22 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431997 ESTABLISHED src=192.0.2.2 dst=192.0.2.1 sport=40079 dport=22 src=192.0.2.6 dst=192.0.2.5 sport=22 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 431996 ESTABLISHED src=192.0.2.2 dst=192.0.2.1 sport=40079 dport=22 src=192.0.2.6 dst=192.0.2.5 sport=22 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 119 TIME_WAIT src=192.0.2.2 dst=192.0.2.1 sport=40079 dport=22 src=192.0.2.6 dst=192.0.2.5 sport=22 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
...
ipv4     2 tcp      6 0 TIME_WAIT src=192.0.2.2 dst=192.0.2.1 sport=40079 dport=22 src=192.0.2.6 dst=192.0.2.5 sport=22 dport=22 [ASSURED] mark=0 zone=0 use=2
```

As you can see, despite the fact that connection has been closed correctly, the associated conntrack entry is still presented in the conntrack table with the `TIME_WAIT` state. And, because, we have only single possible port for SNAT, that is already busy, the new connection attempts fail. Why we don't use this port one more time? Because the system cannot distinguish the reply packets from `192.0.2.6` between current flow in `TIME_WAIT` state and new flow.

Why the conntrack set the connection into the `TIME_WAIT` state instead destroy it I hadn't found out.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.
And of course I want the bloody details. :-)
What is the reason of this delay?
Why does it apply only to port forwarded connections and not to connections that are only NAT'ted?
How can I expect to get the reply if I don't SNAT to the initial port?

Is there another mean to avoid outgoing connexions to, especially, port 25, and not having this problem? SSH tunnelling?

Comment: I don't figure out why do you need `-j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>:25`? What's point to specify the port number? If you'll use just `-j SNAT --to-source <my_local_ip>`, the issue will disappear.

Comment: I don't remember, likely I was stuck to an old tutorial and it seemed logical. Anyway I now switched to a SSH tunnel solution, which seems to work great, even if I also had to solve some specific problems to that. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Accept the answer if it has helped.

Comment: TIME_WAIT is a mandatory state for one side (the one closing first) to account for dup and other lost packets still on internet which could arrive later. see [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#page-39) defining TCP in 1981 (there might be updating RFCs). Schema and also search there for "Knowing When to Keep Quiet".

Comment: @A.B On the client and server sides the connection is completely closed and sockets aren't exists anymore, but on the intermediate linux host the connection is still present in the conntrack table, but it's completely wrong. Likely this is just the especiality of the implementation.